# nodejs client server issue when reconnecting

Tags: node.js, sockets, client-server

I am very new to `nodejs` and I have some client-server implementation, which basically works the following manner : I submit a form which throws data to a client remote server. The latter send me back some new data.

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {

      socket.on('error',function(err){ console.error(err)});

      socket.on('data', function (data) {
          some_method(data)
      }); 
      socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('CONN: disconnected');
        //socket.end();
     });

    app.post('/api/sender', function(req, res) {
          socket.write(some_input);
          res.end();
      });
    }).listen(9000);
```

This works well until the client disconnects itself and reconnects, then I get the following error message :

```
{ [Error: This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE' }
```

And the code crashes at this line `socket.write(some_input)`. Can someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

here's how this could be tackled :

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var clients = {};

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

     server.getConnections(function(err, count) {
            var id = sha1(socket.remoteAddress);
            clients[id] = {
                stream: through(),
                socket: socket,
            }
            clients[id].stream.pipe(socket);
        });
      socket.on('error',function(err){ console.error(err)});

      socket.on('data', function (data) {
          some_method(data)
      }); 
      socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('CONN: disconnected');
        socket.end();
     });

    app.post('/api/sender', function(req, res) {
    // here id is the IP adress got from req
        if (clients[id]) {
            clients[id].stream.write(input);
        }
          res.end();
      });
    }).listen(9000);
};
```